# Как добавить окно в mdiArea d PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Всем привет.
Знающие подскажите пожалуйста как добавлять окна в mdiArea.
Вот я набросал очень простенький пример, но у меня не работает. Я примерно понимаю почему не работает но не знаю как исправить.

QtDesiner

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main_class, base_class = loadUiType('main.ui')
dialog_1_class, dialog_1_base_class = loadUiType("dialog.ui")


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, main_class):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args)
        self.setupUi(self)
        dialog1 = Dialog
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(dialog1)


class Dialog(QWidget, dialog_1_class):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(*args)
        self.setupUi(self)

main = MainWindow()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Скриншот кода + ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст ошибки:

```
TypeError: QMdiArea.addSubWindow(QWidget, Qt.WindowFlags flags=0): 
argument 1 has unexpected type 'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtWrapperType'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно создавать объект:

```
dialog1 = Dialog()
```

У вас просто тип `Dialog` был передан в `self.mdiArea.addSubWindow`